# Extract all, but not to a new folder

Tags: windows-8, zip

In windows 8, there is a nice feature that allows me to extract zip archives easily. The problem is that it always save the file to a newly created folder of the same name.

While I can manually modify this path, the paths are sometimes long and annoying to remove manually.

Is there a way to set it so that default is not to create a new folder, but rather just extract into the parent folder?

I realize this can be done with third party tools, but I am trying to stay within the OS (this is for a work machine).

Are there any reg keys that I can edit or similar to make this work properly (perhaps even add to the context menu)?

Comment: The pathname presented is actually the parent folder and the new foldername is the name of the archive. Extracting to the parent folder is okay for the first time. It usually leads to problems when you extract the next archive.

Comment: @ott-- almost all of the zip files come "the linux standard way" i.e. that they only contain a folder, and all the files are in that. Adding another level of indirection just makes it more annoying.

Comment: Ok, then you need to remove just the last part. I think the whole path is selected, so you could try to replace it by "." and see where you end up.

Comment: "In windows 8, there is a nice feature that allows me to extract zip archives easily" - Is this something new to Win8, or are you talking of the same [crappy](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A138343+is%3Aanswer+%22compressed+folders%22) Compressed Folders feature that has existed for ages?

Comment: @Karan I think its the same thing

Comment: Then I might be wrong, but AFAIK its behaviour cannot be modified.